# It's possible to create constants or similar and use them inside a node description or title in Drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

Let's say we have a download page in a multilingual Drupal site, and we want to define the download version, for example '1.1.0' and a download URL 'http://myweb.com/setup_1_1_0.exe', to use it on the distinct languages nodes for the download page, inserting them as a tag or similar on the tittle and body of the node.

How could it be done in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your need. But I would try to set a `token` called `current_software_version` as `1.1.0`. Node titles and descriptions support the use of Tokens.

Tokens may also be supported within links, when using contributed modules or the redirect module I think.

You typically make custom tokens within a custom module you create. If you want an easier way to make the token value and name, I would look at the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module to build a UI and Admin Edit page for your `current_software_version` value. The Variable module will provide a `token` of the value for use throughout the site for you.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting a little, and with the support of tenken ... first you need to install 'Token Filter' and then enable token replacement in the node body. After installed, go to '/admin/config/content/formats' and enable 'Replace tokens' in your preferred edit mode.

Then install 'Custom Tokens' v7.x-2.0 or greater (important!), flush all caches, and in Structure -> Custom Tokens -> Add token, define your custom token. For example, name: current-version, Token type: custom, ...

Finally in the editor you can insert the token typing something like [custom:current-version].